# How to change Kofax Xml Importer Directory? ACXMLAID move from C

Tags: kofax

How to change Kofax Xml Importer Source Dir ?
Actually my C: is full and i need to move from C:\ACXMLAID\ to F:\ACXMLAID\

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found the solution!

HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Kofax Capture Import Connector - XML\ImagePath\

Added this: -polldir:"F:\ACXMLAID"

Or when register the service use the same parameter.

Thank you.